# How to send malformed data in django unit tests (django REST framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a unit test in DRF to post malformed json to a client. However, as client.post expects a python dict that it serializes to a json string, how can I send a malformed json string to test the response?

```
 def test_create_resource_malformed_data(self):
      """ Send malformed data """
      malformed_data = '{"malformed":"json"}'
      test_response = self.client.post(self.url_create, malformed_data, format="json")
```

relevant traceback:

```
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 66, in _encode_data
ret = renderer.render(data)
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 160, in render
view = renderer_context['view']
KeyError: 'view'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for `Client`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) (the Rest Framework `APIClient` extends Django's `Client`):

> If you provide `content_type` (e.g. `text/xml` for an XML payload), the contents of data will be sent **as-is** in the POST request, using `content_type` in the HTTP Content-Type header.

So you can do this:

```
malformed_data = '{"malformed":"json"}'
test_response = self.client.post(self.url_create, malformed_data, 
                                 content_type="application/json")
```